# Query with List.Contains() not cached

Tags: c#, performance, linq, entity-framework, ienumerable

I am trying to find a way to "cache" the following query, as the compilation of it increases my total render time (this is used in ASP.NET MVC 5 with EF 6.1) from <50ms to ~700ms:

```
var revisions = from i in items
                from r in i.Revisions
                where cultures.Contains(r.Culture.CultureCode)
                group r by new { r.ItemId, r.Culture } into g
                select g.OrderByDescending(r => r.DateCreated).FirstOrDefault();
```

`cultures` is a `List<string>` at the moment and contains normally 1-3 items.

As far as I understood the `IEnumerable.Contains` can't be cached as the length is not known at compile time, but I also tried using an array which did not help.

**UPDATE: The following query is wrong, as it makes "AND"-combination and returns nothing as soon as two cultures are requested.**
<s>At the moment I use the following, which gives me my <50ms render time back, but seems "hacky" to me:</s>

```
var revisions = items.SelectMany(i => i.Revisions);
foreach (var culture in cultures)
    revisions = revisions.Where(r => r.Culture.CultureCode == culture);

var result = from r in revisions
             group r by new { r.ItemId, r.Culture } into g
             select g.OrderByDescending(r => r.DateCreated).FirstOrDefault();
```

**Is there a way to achive the same result without "building the custom query"?**

**Is there a way to write this query so it is cached by EF?**

I do not really care about the ~700ms "on the first hit", but this query is executed on nearly every page (as it loads the text content of a page) - sometimes even multiple times - and would decrease the whole sites performance dramatically...

*P.S.:* I am also open to write the query totaly different.
I get an `IQueryable<T>` with the items and the list with the cultures to get for each item. I then need the newest revision of each item which the culture requested.

The multiple cultures are actualy only used as a "fall-back" - so if I get `{ "de-AT", "de", "en" }` I search the result first for a revision with `de-AT`, then `de` and finally `en` and return the first one found.
If this can already be done "in the database" it would be perfect, but I have no idea how that could work in SQL (the "culture tree" is also saved in the DB and queried/cached elsewhere, so it could be "joined").

Comment: Why do you single out the Contains()? The rest isn't cached either.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Because it is the reason (AFAIK EF does cache that internaly) - if I remove the `Contains` it is also <50ms...

Comment: You're not keeping a context open in MVC are you?

Comment: @HenkHolterman: No - the `DbContext` is in it's own `using`-block for each request. But without the `Contains` EF is caching the "compiled LINQ query", but with it not...

Comment: If the query w/o Contains is fast enough then do that and add `.ToList().Contains(...)`

Comment: @HenkHolterman: That would give me all revisions with any culture from the DB and not only the one(s) I need...

Comment: Yes... you said that was under 50ms

Comment: @HenkHolterman: The second "manual" query does filter (in <50ms) and "before" there where no cultures as I just added that so it is not an option anymore without the filter, but thanks for your time and input anyhow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now I solved it using LINQkit, but I would still prefer beeing able to use `Contains`:

```
var revisions = itemQuery.SelectMany(i => i.Revisions
    .Where(r => r.State == ContentRevisionState.Published).OfType<R>());

revisions = revisions.ForList(cultures, 
    (p, c) => p.Or(r => r.CultureCode == c.CultureCode));

revisions = revisions.OrderByDescending(r => r.Culture.Position)
    .ThenByDescending(r => r.DateCreated)
    .Include(r => r.Author).Include(r => r.Culture);

var revision = await revisions.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

and

```
public static IQueryable<T> ForList<T, K>(this IQueryable<T> items, List<K> list,
    Func<Expression<Func<T, bool>>, K, Expression<Func<T, bool>>> condition)
{
    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<T>();
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        var tmp = item; // local copy for deferred execution
        predicate = condition(predicate, tmp);
    }
    return items.AsExpandable().Where(predicate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**:

You may want to precompile the query. More about precompiling queries here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336024.aspx

---

You can just store the query in a static variable:

```
private static var query = from i in items
                           from r in i.Revisions
                           where cultures.Contains(r.Culture.CultureCode)
                           group r by new { r.ItemId, r.Culture } into g
                           select g.OrderByDescending(r => r.DateCreated);
```

And then invoke it every time to get the result without causing it to recompile:

```
var revisions = query.FirstOrDefault();
```

You can obtain the same with this mechanism:

```
private static var query = null;

...
...

if (query == null)
{
    query = ... // initialize it here
}
```

This way you don't need all references to be static, too.

Comment: And will that be any faster?

Comment: If you force the query to be precompiled it surely won't be re-compiled each time. I've added a link to the MSDN source. It is a long article and I can't just copy+paste it here.

Comment: Thanks for your input but this does not work: `CompiledQuery` does not support my parameters (`IQueryable<T>` and `List<string>`) and your "static approach" caches "the exact query", but `items` and `cultures` do change from request to request - I just need the "compiled LINQ" cached (as it happens without the `Contains`)...